# ENTER key not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

while  i am pressing enter key its calls function which automatically refreshing the page. the function i wrote for cancel button

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div >
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required ng-model="name" />
    </div>
    <div >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required ng-model="lname" />
    </div>

    <div >
        <button type="Cancel"  ng-click=clearDetails()>Clear</button>
        <button type="submit"  ng-click=addDetails() ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>                  
    </div>
</form>
```

after filling any of textfield press enters its calls the clearDetails function

```
$scope.addDetails = function() {
var postObj = new Object();
// add details stuff here   
}

$scope.clearDetails = function() {
    //refresh the page stuff here
    //here i am redirecting to the same page
}
```

Comment: have you tried putting `alert()` in `clearDetails()`? is it ever got called on pressing enter key?

Comment: I debugging it in browser put the breakpoint in clearDetails function()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of the cancel button to reset:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required ng-model="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required ng-model="lname" />
    </div>
    <button type="reset" ng-click=clearDetails()>Clear</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click=addDetails() ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On many browser enter consider as submit form or associate with first button click .. just a suggestion move submit button up and cancel button down in html it might solve the problem.

Comment: The default behaviour of _any_ button whose `type` tag is not set explicitly to `reset` or `button` is to `submit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

make sure there must be space between two attributes of submit button. You wrote the code as

```
<button **type="submit"ng-click=addDetails()** ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

it must be

```
<button **type="submit" ng-click=addDetails()** ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
```